# google chrome tabs show blocks instead letters of page titles

Tags: google-chrome, browser, unicode

on windows 7 after updating chrome to 41 version webpage Armenian unicode titles stopped displaying right, it shows blocks instead of unicode letters. any suggestions ?

Comment: Sounds like it's now using a different font for the window title which does not have the requisite glyphs in it. Let me go check if Chrome for Windows has a checkbox "use system title bar and border" in settings, maybe twiddling that will make a difference.

Comment: I have tried to add Armenian language in Settings-Languages, but still no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved! I have just changed windows scheme.